# I think "contrary / opposite" to you

Tags: word-usage, difference, phrases

> - We have never had a conversation, I don't think, so I am not familiar with your character.
>   I hope you are interested in intellectual disputation, friendly argumentation and logical analysis, Sam.
>   If so, please respond in kind.
>   If you are not very interested in logical thought and theological arguments, or if you are impatient with subtleties of reason or prefer not to treat me like a friend simply because I think ............ on a number of significant issues, then please give this a pass.

a. opposite to you 
b. contrary to you

To me, both of the offered options are acceptable and idiomatically natural. However, I need to make sure whether "opposite" and "contrary" can be used interchangeably here in order to make fixed phrases with equal meanings.

P.S. [The similar thread](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/221556/opposite-to-vs-contrary-to) in the forum was posted by me and I didn't find it that helpful to answer this specific question about a fixed phrase.

Comment: What's wrong with 'differently'? It seems to be a perfect, one-word fit.

Comment: I need to discover a fixed phrase @JMB when it comes to an opposite viewpoint. Otherwise, there are many ways to convey the same message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither one is usable in your example.

- The construction "opposite to" only works as an adjective: "The shop is opposite to the bookstore" works because it modifies the noun "shop"*
- "Contrary to" really works the same way. I could say "My beliefs are contrary to yours," and that works because it's modifying the noun "beliefs." But to say "I think contrary to" is to try to make an adjective work as an adverb.
- You *could* say "I think **contrarily** to you"—that's a perfectly valid adverb—but honestly, it sounds a bit silly. (Plus, "contrarily" has a connotation of obstinate, perverse, or ornery, and I'm not sure you want to suggest that you think in that way!)
- The suggestion of "I think differently than you" really is the best "fixed phrase" you'll get to fit this context.

* Ok, ok, really it's a prepositional complement, but let's keep it simple.